Is it recommended to include the Makefile itself as a dependency in make recipes?
When developing Makefiles, I often need to run a 'clean' target when I edit the Makefile itself to ensure that the newest recipes are executed. It seems like there must be a way to include the Makefile itself in the list of dependencies. Is there a conventional approach to solving this problem?

simply run make with the -B flag in development.
You generally would not want to include the Makefile as dependency, because you'd need to add it to every single leaf dependency, and that would be horrible.
alternatively: let your shell help you: alias mk="make clean;make " would allow you to type mk where you want to type make during development.
Also note that if you have so much Makefile that you need to do heavy development on it, a meta-build system might be the right thing to you, to get rid of that necessity. cmake is probably the most popular tool, but meson does also get a lot of usage, and is a bit less pitfall-ridden. These tools automatically re-run the changed rules (or every target if changes are pervasive); saves one a lot of confusion.

That, and once the Makefile stabilises, the slightest change would cause everything to be rebuilt, even if the change only affected a single target (or none at all).

@StephenKitt it is better to build too much rather than too little (for safety), although it is best to build exactly the right amount. The answer suggests building everything every time (either via -B for an alias), which definitely errs to the too much side. Adding Makefile as a dependency is fine, If you know the build system inside out then you can often shortcut big rebuilds by a "edit the Makefile, run 'make -t' to touch everything, run 'rm xxx.o; make' to rebuild then things that you know need to be rebuilt and leave the rest". Obviously error prone, but can speed up development.

@icarus I don't disagree, and for most programming languages that take some time to compile there's good caching compilers frontends, so that if you run e.g. gcc with exactly the same flags on exactly the same files, it takes the resulting file from an "offsite" cache instead of running the compiler again. make -B  together with ccache or sccache is indeed pretty manageable for medium sized projects. For large projects: why are you handling Makefiles manually? this really shouts "you need something more elaborate than plain Make with nothing on top".
